Self-descriptive
The answer is 4 letters long. But in order for this puzzle to be complete I should've added one more image, which I intentionally excluded, depicting "something". What is this "something" given the answer? The answer to that... is also 4 letters long.



The answer is:

 TAGS

Because the 4 images represent...

 ...the four tags that have been used on this post!

 1. enigmatic-puzzle - a jigsaw puzzle with a question mark suggesting a mystery or enigma.

 2. visual - represented by an eye.

 3. knowledge - "no ledge"

 4. rebus - a bus in a circle of arrows suggesting repetition ('re').

Now let's use the numbers to...

 ...index into the tag names and choose the nth letter in each case:

 enigma[t]ic-puzzle (7)
 visu[a]l (5)
 knowled[g]e (8)
 rebu[s] (5)

 These spell TAGS, our hidden answer!

Of course, there is something missing...

 ...because the answer to this puzzle is a single word, it should also have been tagged with the word tag, meaning that a depiction of a WORD is missing!


Well done! As I said under Hexomino's answer you were slightly faster so you get the tick

rot13(ercrgvgvba be erplpyvat)?

I think the answer is

 TAGS

Reasoning

 Notice how each image corresponds to one of the tags attached to the question - in order, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, knowledge ("no ledge"), rebus (bus inside symbol for recycling).
 If we take the letter in each word corresponding to the number above it, it spells out TAGS

What has been intentionally excluded

 I believe it is the tag WORD which would not be used to form the word TAGS and so, has been omitted as a tag, even though appropriate.


Wow, 15 seconds in it!

Correct! But I'm giving the tick to Stiv since he was slightly faster.

@Stiv, well done, you have a more complete explanation too.
